# Deobfuscating huge and complex code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

can someone help me how to deobfuscate this code? I spent a lot of time to try it, and no any results...

http://pastebin.com/raw/682hPUqh

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and the [tour] to see how and what to ask here. This question is currently off topic

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Probably your best bet with trying to get anywhere, but as for the variable names and such, there's no way of being able to define what they once were called, you'd just have to work it out.